# How to measure response time for actions in Android apps?

Tags: android, performance, appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I need to figure out a way to measure response time for certain actions in release builds of some Android apps.

An example of what I am trying to measure is as follows :-
In Snapchat, after recording a video, I need to measure the time between

1. User presses the My Story option
2. The progress circle in the upper left corner of the screen completes

I have tried using UI Automator -> wait(Until.findObject()) and Appium -> waitForElementById() with start/stop timer before and after the methods executed but the results obtained are not good.

Any suggestion or ideas would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis();` to get your times and subtract them to get your response time, for example :

- when the first method is called  > `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`
- when the second method is called or ended  > `long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Now if you want to know the time that has passed you can use :

```
Long timeThatPassed = endTime - startTime;
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html):

> currentTimeMillis() 
>   Returns the current time in milliseconds.

Comment: That's exactly what I did before and after calling the methods I mentioned

Comment: I did not understand that from the question, and was it not accurate?