# response time in android not working as intended (Java)

Tags: java, android, time, user-input

I'm currently coding an android app, which requires the user to input a number in response to something that is on the screen. I am trying to measure how long this takes. So I looked it up and found this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55867763/how-to-measure-response-time-for-actions-in-android-apps) about it. I immidently started coding, but soon i ran into a problem. It was not working. Here is my code for it:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    public static long time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public static long time_end;
    public static double time_needed;
    TextView showTimeNeededTextView;
    public View onCreateView(

            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState

    ) {
       

        View fragmentFirstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        

        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        
        showTimeNeededTextView = fragmentFirstLayout.findViewById(R.id.time_needed_TW);
       
        return fragmentFirstLayout;
}

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
        // checks if input is null
        if(editText.getText() != null){
            end_timer();
        }
    
        return true;

       

}
        public void end_timer(){
        time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        time_needed = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(time_end - time_start)) ;
        time_needed = (double)Math.round(time_needed*100d)/100d;
        System.out.println("Time it took the user to input: "+time_needed);
}
}
```

When running the code and trying it out for myself tho, time_needed was always rounded wrong, and didnt relate to any amount of time it took to answer. (Example: I intentionally wait 5 seconds to test the code, but it shows that it took me 1.0 seconds)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlBhK.png)

Is there any way to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: double time_needed = (double)((time_needed / 1000) % 60 it will give you time difference in seconds.

Comment: to convert it up-to 2 decimal points 
String.format("%.2f", time_needed );